# How to re-fetch MockProvider before a "fireEvent" from @testing-library/react?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, graphql, react-testing-library

I'm trying to execute a test here that basically should execute some action after clicking a button using the mocked data returned by graphQL

```
<MockedProvider
      mocks={mocks}>
      <button data-testid="my-button">Execute Actions using mocked Data</button>
    </MockedProvider>
```

```
fireEvent.click(myButton);
```

When it fires the button, the data received from graphQL is empty.
Here is my mock:

```
return {
    request: {
      query: QUERY,
      variables: {
        marketCodes: '',
        years: '',
        minDate: null,
        maxDate: null,
        limit: 100
      }
    },
    result: { data },
    newData: jest.fn(() => ({ data }))
  };
```

Can anyone help me with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
fireEvent.click(myButton);
await waitForElementToBeRemoved(() => screen.queryByTestId("loader"));
// now you can expect the mocked data
```

After you have any action that leads to some async functionality, you need to wait for that spinner to go away from the dom and then only new state will be available to you.

[Here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/development-testing/testing/#testing-the-success-state), you can see they are using Promise resolve, if you don't have any spinner or loader.

You can refer [this](https://testing-library.com/docs/guide-disappearance/#waiting-for-disappearance) too. And, try using [`user-event`](https://testing-library.com/docs/ecosystem-user-event). It's the recommended way for user interactions.

And, instead of using MockedProvider, you can directly mock api requests using [msw](https://mswjs.io/). I've been using the same and really happy with it.